# Shading after making hole/boolean

Tags: modifiers, shaders

so I've been working on my gun project for a little bit now, and I am having some trouble with the shading. As you can see here I've made a hole and joined another object using union in boolean modifier:

[image]

However the shading seems to look very bad and I don't know how to fix this.
(For the other hole I sculpted it instead of using booleans)

Comment: Hello, is it a problem of shading or is it a bad topology? maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: It's very common to have shading issues after boolean operations. Josh Gambrell has some great videos on fixing this exact thing. https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCXfGjwohMgPm4Ng2e1FXySw